# Screenshot in Unity/Ubuntu within VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, unity, screenshot

I'm trying to take a screenshot of Firefox running on Unity/Ubuntu 16.04 inside VirtualBox 5.1.2. Pressing <kbd>Prt Scrn</kbd> pops open a little app called **Screenshot** but the screenshot shown is only ever the desktop, with no application windows visible.

My host operating system is Windows 10 Pro.

Does anyone know how to resolve this and get screenshot functionality working inside VirtualBox?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may take a screenshot with VirtualBox's built-in screenshot capability, either through pressing <kbd>RightCtrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> (or <kbd>LeftCmd</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> on Mac), which will open up a save file window on the host), or with

```
$ VBoxManage controlvm vmname screenshotpng screenshot.png
```

from the command line of the host, where `vmname` is the name of the virtual machine and `screenshot.png` is the name of the PNG image you'd like to create.

Comment: I never knew this, so thanks for the tip - not a solution, but does get me around the problem.

Answer (score 5):

The VirtualBox has its own buit-in screenshot utility, which you can use via Host+E (Host is right Ctrl) keyboard shortcut. Alternatively, you could use `gnome-screenshot` which comes with Unity by default, and export the file later to imgur or other service. Shared folder is also an option, but you will need to have guest additions installed in order for that to work

On a side note, Ubuntu has <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Print_Screen</kbd> shortcut for taking screenshot of currently focused window, which you can use as an alternative.

Comment: `Alt+Prt Scrn` also only captures the desktop unfortunately